# Split a List into chunks by an Element

Tags: java, collections, split, java-8, java-stream

I have a collection of Objects (Pos) with this model :

```
public class Pos {
    private String beforeChangement;
    private String type;
    private String afterChangement;
}
```

The list of objects is like this :

```
[
Pos(beforeChangement=Découvrez, type=VER, afterChangement=découvrir), 
Pos(beforeChangement=un, type=DET, afterChangement=un),
Pos(beforeChangement=large, type=ADJ, afterChangement=large), 
Pos(beforeChangement=., type=SENT, afterChangement=.), 
Pos(beforeChangement=Livraison, type=NOM, afterChangement=livraison), 
Pos(beforeChangement=et, type=KON, afterChangement=et), 
Pos(beforeChangement=retour, type=NOM, afterChangement=retour), 
Pos(beforeChangement=., type=SENT, afterChangement=.), 
Pos(beforeChangement=achetez, type=VER, afterChangement=acheter), 
Pos(beforeChangement=gratuitement, type=ADV, afterChangement=gratuitement), 
Pos(beforeChangement=., type=SENT, afterChangement=.), 
Pos(beforeChangement=allez, type=VER, afterChangement=aller), 
Pos(beforeChangement=faites, type=VER, afterChangement=faire), 
Pos(beforeChangement=vite, type=ADV, afterChangement=vite), 
Pos(beforeChangement=chers, type=ADJ, afterChangement=cher), 
Pos(beforeChangement=clients, type=NOM, afterChangement=client)]
Pos(beforeChangement=., type=SENT, afterChangement=.)
]
```

I want to split this List of Objects by the the field of beforeChangement or afterChangement == "." to have this format (A List of List) `List<List<SOP>>` :

```
[

[Pos(beforeChangement=Découvrez, type=VER, afterChangement=découvrir), 
Pos(beforeChangement=un, type=DET, afterChangement=un),
Pos(beforeChangement=large, type=ADJ, afterChangement=large)],

[Pos(beforeChangement=Livraison, type=NOM, afterChangement=livraison), 
Pos(beforeChangement=et, type=KON, afterChangement=et), 
Pos(beforeChangement=retour, type=NOM, afterChangement=retour)],

[Pos(beforeChangement=achetez, type=VER, afterChangement=acheter), 
Pos(beforeChangement=gratuitement, type=ADV, afterChangement=gratuitement)],


[Pos(beforeChangement=allez, type=VER, afterChangement=aller), 
Pos(beforeChangement=faites, type=VER, afterChangement=faire), 
Pos(beforeChangement=vite, type=ADV, afterChangement=vite), 
Pos(beforeChangement=chers, type=ADJ, afterChangement=cher), 
Pos(beforeChangement=clients, type=NOM, afterChangement=client)]

]
```

Is like performing an inverse flatMap to have a List of Array or List (Chunks) after splitting by a field of object that is the String "."

do you have any idea about how to do it using Streams ?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm, I would like to solve your problem using a simple loop like this :

```
List<List<Pos>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<Pos> part = new ArrayList<>();
for(Pos pos : listPos){
    if(pos.getBeforeChangement().equals(".") || pos.getAfterChangement().equals(".")){
        result.add(part);//If the condition is correct then add the sub list to result list
        part = new ArrayList<>();// and reinitialize the sub-list
    } else {
        part.add(pos);// else just put the Pos object to the sub-list
    }
}
//Just in case the listPos not end with "." values then the last part should not be escaped
if(!part.isEmpty()){
    result.add(part);
}
```

---

Note, the question is not clear enough your Object class is named `SOP` and the List of Object is `Pos` which one is correct, In my answer I based to `public class Pos{..}` instead of `public class SOP{..}`.

---

- [**take a look at the Ideone demo**](https://ideone.com/GZCKyV)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I made a correction Pos and SOP is the same .

Comment: There's a significant problem with this solution, namely when the list of `Pos` does *not* end with `.`, your code will **skip** the entire last sentence.

Comment: No @TomaszLinkowski check the outputs in The question, the Object which have `.` is not include in the result. also you can compare with the outputs of the Question and the Outputs of the demo mentioned in my answer

Comment: You're right that - according to the question - the objects containing `.` should be skipped (I did not notice it, and my answer does not do it). But what I mean is that if the input list did *not* end with a "dot"-object, your code is simply **skipping** the entire last sublist instead of either including such sublist or throwing an error. See this [clone of your snippet](https://ideone.com/2moo0K), where I removed the last line from `listPos`. Note that `"allez", "faites", "vite", "chers", "clients"` is missing from the output.

Answer (score 2):

with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library you can use [`groupRuns`](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) method to split list for list of lists.

For example:

```
List<List<Pos>> collect = StreamEx.of(originalList.stream())
            .groupRuns((p1, p2) -> !(".".equals(p2.beforeChangement) || ".".equals(p2.afterChangement)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Method `groupRuns` returns `Stream` of lists. In example above it are lists where first element with `.`.

You can filter  out these elements later. For example using `map` method:

```
StreamEx.of(originalList.stream())
            .groupRuns((p1, p2) -> !(".".equals(p2.beforeChangement) || ".".equals(p2.afterChangement))) // returns Stream of lists with '.' element
            .map(l -> l.stream()
                        .filter(p -> !(".".equals(p.beforeChangement) || ".".equals(p.afterChangement))) //filter out element with '.'
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()) // filter out empty lists
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: As far as I understand, though, this code will place the dots in separate lists, right?

Comment: how we can exclude the "." in the pipeline ?

Comment: Instead of `map` + `filter` related to dots (and an extra `collect` there), I would simply use the following: `.filter(l -> !isPeriod(l.get(0)))` where `boolean isPeriod(Pos pos) { return ".".equals(pos.beforeChangement) || ".".equals(pos.afterChangement); }`

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski your example is filter out whole list if first element is '.'-element

Comment: Now that I read the code more carefully I understood that the periods are *not* placed into separate lists. I got confused because I thought the predicate in `groupRuns` is `(p1, p2) -> !isPeriod(p1) && !isPeriod(p2)` while in fact it is `(p1, p2) -> !isPeriod(p2)`. This is a bit strange condition, though, because it means the periods go at the *beginnings* of the lists. However, you're right that my filtering proposal wouldn't work. Instead, I would change the predicate to `(p1, p2) -> !isPeriod(p1)`, and then removed the last element from each list using `peek` if it matched `isPeriod`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would be conservative here, and I wouldn't use `Stream`s (although it's possible).

The following snippet does what you need:

```
List<Pos> posList;
List<List<Pos>> result = new ArrayList<>();
boolean startNewSentence = true;
for (Pos pos : posList) {
    if (startNewSentence) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    startNewSentence = isPeriod(pos);
    if (!startNewSentence) {
        result.get(result.size() - 1).add(pos);
    }
}
```

where:

```
boolean isPeriod(Pos pos) {
    return ".".equals(pos.beforeChangement()) || ".".equals(pos.afterChangement());
}
```

PS. Note there's no such word as "changement" in English. The noun from verb "change" is also "[change](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/change)".

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. this logic can solve my problem +1

Comment: @Dr.Mza I updated the code so that the elements with periods are not included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your object name for the list is `SOP` object is `listSOP`. Then

```
List<SOP> listSOP = new ArrayList<>();
.... populate your list. 
Map<String,List<SOP>> map = listSOP.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SOP::getBeforeChangement)
```

This should return a `Map` of type `<String(BeforeChangement), List<SOP>>`.

Here `getBeforeChangement` is the getter method in your `SOP` class which should return value of variable `beforeChangement`

Comment: This will not work: it will group together all the `SOP`s with the same `beforeChangement` instead of partitioning the original list into ordered sublists.

Answer (score 0):

[`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) may help you.